# How to transfer large folders to virtual machines on azure

Tags: azure, file-transfer

I want to transfer a large folder (24,4GB) to the virtual machine on Azure. The virtual machine has windows 10 OS. Could anyone suggest ways to transfer files? thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [Azure Storage File share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction) to mount it locally and on the remote virtual machine. Use it as you would use any other network folder and transfer your files through it.

See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) for more information on how to set it up.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  The only thing that wasn't immediately clear to me was that a File Share is a component of an Azure Storage Account resource.  After you create the file share, manual connection is very easy; just hit the "Connect" button in the Azure portal and copy/paste the given commands.